# Select level above in iteratively created nested list with Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested

I have trawled through so many questions on lists and I can't find what I'm looking for.

I have a string with braces wrapping some values and some other nested pairs of braces containing values. I don't know the deepest level the structure is nested, but it might look something like this:

> {121{12}12{211}2}

I want to iterate over this string and transfer it to a nested list in a way similar to the following pseudocode:

```
for i in thestring
if there is a leftbrace { start a new list inside the current list
elseif there is a rightbrace } close the current list and select the list on the level above
else add i to currently selected list
```

I have no idea how to go up a list level and close the current sublist

Comment: You probably want a recursive parsing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def listify(s):
    i = iter(s)
    l = []
    for c in i:
        if c == '{':
            l.append(listify(i))
        elif c == '}':
            return l
        else:
            l.append(c)
    return l[0]
```

The trick is to use a recursive function so that the stack takes care of keeping track which list you're in. We use `iter` so that we can pass the string to recursive calls without the letters we have already processed.

```
>>>listify(s)
['1', '2', '1', ['1', '2'], '1', '2', ['2', '1', '1'], '2']
```

Comment: so how do I access a particular nested list created using this?

Comment: say if I want to access the 2nd item in the second sublist on the bottom level?(in this case a 1 - and the third number from the right)

Comment: Lists aren't really very good for that.  It sounds like you may want a more tree-like structure

Comment: I see lots of packages in python that build trees, but is there a tree data type? Because I would prefer not to use other people's packages and just use lists with my own parent/child indexing system

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using regex and `ast.literal_eval` to create a set of tuples:

```
In [78]: s = "{121{12}12{211}2}"

In [79]: new = re.sub(r'(})(?!$)|(?<!^)({)',lambda x : {'{': ',(', '}': ',),'}[x.group(0)], s)

In [80]: ast.literal_eval(new)
Out[80]: {121, (211,), 2, 12, (12,)}
```